# Can an Azure DevOps Work Item Template contain a simple multi-line text input?

Tags: tfs, customization, azure-devops-server-2022, work-item-type

We are running on-premises Azure DevOps Server 2022.0.1 (AzureDevOpsServer_20230418.1)

I have added a String input to the Task WIT in my system
From the Fields section:

```
<FIELD name="Cost Description" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.CostDescription" type="String">
    <HELPTEXT>Short description of the costs involved in the task</HELPTEXT>
</FIELD>
```

In the `<WebLayout>` block in one of the `<Section><Group>`s, I added this:

```
<Control Label="Cost Description" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.CostDescription" />
```

However, the resulting form input is a single-line text box.

My question is, can the `Type="FieldControl"` attribute be something that specifies a multi-line input, but without all the overhead of a `Type="HtmlFieldControl"`?  (Seems there ought to be reference document of attributes, etc., but I've not found one).

I considered just using the `Type="HtmlFieldControl"` attribute but this field does not need that overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The reference doc is [WebLayout and Control elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=tfs-2017). The subsection [Control element Type attribute syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=tfs-2017#control-types) has examples of each supported value for `Type`.

The built-in choices are `FieldControl` or `HTMLFieldControl`. There isn't a simple multiline text control.

However, in the Azure DevOps Marketplace there is a [Multiline Plain Text Field](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=krypu.multiline-plain-text-field) extension you may want to test out. I haven't used this extension and I know nothing about it except the Marketplace description and the GitHub repo listed under the Project Details.